# Android managing activity from custom state machine

Tags: android, android-activity, state, android-service

I have the application that is polling the http server.
Depending on the returned JSON the application should change the activity at the front.

My question is, how to achieve that? Should I use Android's service facility?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON object in an `AsyncTask` and then update the views in `onPostExecute()` method of the AsyncTask. There is no need for a service though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it is not what I am looking for. I have a background task that periodically request server and switches the activity depending on the server response. Will you give me any hint, please? Should I use custom Application class?